# global directory for npm and yarn

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, yarnpkg

Since I have a docker image for node js and want to install global node_modules directory as well as local using volumes e. g a part of my docker-compose file looks as below.

```
...
node:
    image: node
    volumes:
      - ./webroot:/var/app
      - ./global_node_modules:/var/node_global
    environment:
      - NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/var/node_global
      - YARN_CONFIG_PREFIX=/var/node_global
      - PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/var/node_global/bin
    working_dir: /var/app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

I have `./global_node_modules` directory which is mapped to a volume on node container `/var/node_global` where I want to install global packages
when I run `npm --global` or `yarn global add`.  npm is respecting the env variable `NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX` but that is not true for yarn. e.g

After `npm install vue-cli --global`

> ls -al /var/node_global/bin
>
> vue -> ../lib/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue
>
> vue-init -> ../lib/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue-init
>
> vue-list -> ../lib/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue-list

After `yarn global add vue-cli`

> ls -al /var/node_global/bin
>
> vue -> ../../../usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue
>
> vue-init -> ../../../usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue-init
>
> vue-list -> ../../../usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue-list

I was wondering what makes yarn install file in different directory. It seems to be linking the binaries but that is not sufficient.

Comment: I think the directory I am looking is `yarn global dir 
/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global`